# How can I get reliable counts from a SQLAlchemy query with joins?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy with PostgreSQL. Some of my queries involved joining related tables and filtering based on values in the joined tables. At times these joins and and filters can be multiple relationships deep. My problem is that I have not found a way to get a reliable number of results when using limit. I understand that limit is affecting the row count and not the count of top-level model objects returned by my query. Are there any techniques or tricks for getting around this issue?

Here is a simple (and probably bad) example. Imagine a database with tables and corresponding SQLAlchemy model classes for `Company`, `Department`, and `Employee`. Obviously there can be many departments in a company and many employees in a department. I might try to get 20 companies with employees named Bob like this:

```
query = Company.query
query = query.join(Department)
query = query.join(Employee)
query.filter(Employee.name == "Bob")
query.limit(20)
result = query.all()
```

Assuming there are many Bobs out there, this query will not yield 20 companies. Is there a way to structure such a query to return a specific count of companies when joining and filtering in this manner?

Comment: AFAIK this is not really solvable in an easy way. You'll need to group by `Company`, which may be a too big hit on performance though.